# Set declared parameter value and CONCAT column name

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have table with columns Char1, Char2, Char3..... Each of these columns contain some value. I declared variable @i and in while loop I'm trying to concat it to the Char table column name.
Also, I declared parameter @current in my query and then I'm trying to set its value in the query.

```
set @tmp = cast(@i as varchar(2))
select @current = 'Char' + @tmp
from SerialNumberFormat
where Example = 'XXXXXXXXXX'
```

When I execute the query @current has value Char1, Char2, Char3...etc, instead the value of the column.
How I can set column value instead column name in @current?

Comment: You need to use dynamic SQL.  But you might ponder why you have such columns anyway in a table.  The data would be better represented with a single column and separate rows for the values.

Comment: @GordonLinoff you are right, but the table is already created and there are lot of data inside. It's not good solution, but I have to deal with it because I can't change it

Comment: I can't say I actually understand your goal here. Some sample data and expected results would help.

Comment: @Larnu I edited the post. Hope it is more clear now

Comment: select @current = Concat(Char1, Char2, Char3)

Comment: I don't see any sample data *or* expected results, @VasilGorgiev ?

Comment: @Ulla-Brendholdt I already tried with concat('Char', @tmp), but it is same. Result is Char1, Char2, Char3...instead their values

Comment: Concat without colon: Concat(Char1, Char2, .....) not ('Char1', 'Char2', ...)

Answer (score 0):

```
select @current = Concat(Char1, Char2, Char3)
from SerialNumberFormat
where Example = 'X59AA419010045'
```

Comment: Code only answers are rarely helpful. Please elaborate on your code and explain why and how this solves the question.

Answer (score 0):

Solution which I found and works for me is executing [`sp_executesql` stored procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
set @SQL = N'select @currentOUT = Char' + @tmp + ' from SerialNumberFormat
where Example = ''XXXXXXXXX'''
SET @ParmDefinition = N'@currentOUT nvarchar(10) OUTPUT' 
exec sp_executesql @SQL, @ParmDefinition, @currentOUT = @current OUTPUT
select @current
```

Answer (score -1):

Dynamic Sql like this may work for you

```
Declare @i int = 5

Declare @tmp varChar (10) = @i

Declare @Sql nVarChar(Max) =    'select Char' + @tmp + '
from SerialNumberFormat
where Example = ''X59AA419010045'''

exec sp_executesql @Sql
```

Comment: your approach with sp_executesql was correct for me. I solved it using sp_executedsql